# What is use of "expect_file()" function in Codeception?

Tags: php, yii, yii2, phpunit, codeception

Hi i am new to codeception unit testing and i am using it with Yii2. I know the user of functions `expect_not()` and `expect_that()` and also know little about `expect()` function and uses it to check key in error array.

However I don't know the use of `expect_file()`. I searched little in internet but found not any good help. can anyone please give me little description about the use of this function.

Comment: expect_not, expect_that and expect_file functions do not belong to Codeception, where did you find them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`expect_file()` is used to verify with assertions specific to file system objects. It has two parameters (one is optional).

If you call this function with a single parameter, it will be used as the Subject Under Test file name. if it is called with two parameters, will be used as a description to display if the assertion fails but if you if you call it with 0 or more than two arguments it will throw a bad method call exceptions.

You can use it like this

```
expect_file('filename.txt')->exists();
expect_file('filename.txt')->notExists();
```

BTW `expect_file()` is an alternate function for `verify_file()`.

Comment: what library does it belong to?